# XSLT Newbie - Looping and Matching Elements

Tags: xslt

Brand new to XSLT but managed to hack my way through to extract the data I needed...

I'm now stuck on extracting the data into a required format to upload into a database...  I need to match each PGBLK with its corresponding TASK (please see example below).

Pretty sure I want to use XSLT Looping but to be honest I'm not sure, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <PGBLK CHAPNBR="05" CHG="U" CONFNBR="0" PGBLKNBR="2" REVDATE="20160608" SECTNBR="00" SUBJNBR="00">
  <TASK CHAPNBR="05" CHG="R" FUNC="912" PGBLKNBR="2" REVDATE="20160520" SECTNBR="00" SEQ="001"
    SUBJNBR="00"/>
    <EFFECT EFFRG="000" EFFTEXT="ALL"/>
  <TASK CHAPNBR="05" CHG="R" FUNC="910" PGBLKNBR="2" REVDATE="20160520" SECTNBR="00" SEQ="801"
    SUBJNBR="00">
    <EFFECT EFFRG="000" EFFTEXT="ALL"/>
   </TASK>
</PGBLK>
```

Current XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="RTM">

 <REFERENCES>
    <xsl:attribute name="DATE">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-date()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="//PGBLK">
            <REF>
             <PGBLK>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(@CHAPNBR, '-', @SECTNBR, '-', @SUBJNBR, '-', @PGBLKNBR, '-0')"/>
                </PGBLK>
            <TASK>
             <xsl:value-of select="TASK/concat(@CHAPNBR, '-', @SECTNBR, '-', @SUBJNBR, '-', @FUNC, '-', @SEQ, ',')"/>
            </TASK>
            </REF>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </REFERENCES>
</xsl:template>
```

Current XML Output:

```
<REFERENCES DATE="2017-11-15-06:00">
 <REF>
  <PGBLK>05-00-00-2-0</PGBLK>
  <TASK>05-00-00-912-001, 05-00-00-910-801,</TASK>
 </REF>
</REFERENCES>
```

Desired XML Output:

```
<REFERENCES DATE="2017-11-15-06:00">
 <REF>
  <PGBLK>05-00-00-2-0</PGBLK><TASK>05-00-00-912-001</TASK>
  <PGBLK>05-00-00-2-0</PGBLK><TASK>05-00-00-910-801</TASK>
 </REF>
</REFERENCES>
```

Comment: XSLT does not have looping *per se*.  On a conceptual level, even `for-each` is better construed quite literally: it allows you to specify a template to be instantiated for each one of zero or more values.  XSLT is a declarative language with functional feel and style.  Trying to apply procedural programming paradigms to it tends to turn out messy.

Comment: Anyway, with respect to your problem, it looks like you want to create a separate `<PGBLK>` element in the result tree for each `<TASK>` in the input tree, even though in the input, more than one `<TASK>` may be grouped together  in the same `<PGBLK>`.  Is this correct?  Additionally, is it possible that a `<PGBLK>` in the input tree haz zero `<TASK>`s?  If so, then how should that be transformed?

Comment: Also, you present a template for `<RTM>` elements, but there aren't any such elements in the input you've presented.  How should that be reconciled?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts... so maybe I should look at massaging the data into into the required format maybe in Excel...

Comment: Correct on the <PGBLK> element in the result tree for each <TASK>... and there are many instances where there are more than one <TASK> within a <PGBLK>.  It is possible that a <PGBLK> in the input tree has zero <TASK>... current XSLT seems to be handling these instances...  (i.e.) <AMMREF><PGBLK>21-26-00-0-0</PGBLK<TASK/></AMM-REF>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your primary question of how to map `<TASK>` elements to their parent `<PGBLK>`elements, that's pretty easy: select the `<TASK>`s for transformation, and inside their template either

- access the parent via an XPath expression (e.g. `..`)
- provide parent data via a variable from a lexically surrounding scope or via a template parameter provided by the template's dynamic scope.

The process is slightly complicated by the possibility that a `<PGBLK>` might have zero `<TASK>`'s, but it's not that hard.  Here's a variation that sticks close to your original template:

```
<xsl:template match="RTM">
  <!-- NOTE: no need for xsl-attribute unless the attribute name
       or namespace is dynamically determined -->
  <REFERENCES DATE="{current-date()}">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//PGBLK">
      <!-- capture the relevant details of the current PGBLK for re-use
           in nested contexts -->
      <xsl:variable name="blk-code"
          select="concat(@CHAPNBR, '-', @SECTNBR, '-', @SUBJNBR, '-', @PGBLKNBR, '-0')"/>

      <REF>

        <!-- transform all the PGBLK's TASKs, providing a PGBLK with each: -->
        <xsl:for-each select="TASK">
          <PGBLK>
            <xsl:value-of select="$blk-code"/>
          </PGBLK>
          <TASK>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@CHAPNBR, '-', @SECTNBR, '-', @SUBJNBR, '-', @FUNC, '-', @SEQ)"/>
          </TASK>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- handle the case of a PGBLK without any TASKs (in which case the
             for-each will not have added anything to the result tree: -->
        <xsl:if test="not(TASK)">
          <PGBLK>
            <xsl:value-of select="$blk-code"/>
          </PGBLK>
          <TASK/>
        </xsl:if>

      </REF>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </REFERENCES>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much... this XSLT is even cleaner and I truly appreciate you taking the time to insert the comments. It helps so much... now I understand what's happening and why it happening!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map `PGBLK` to `REF` and then each `TASK` to a pair of `PGBLK` and `TASK` then the following should help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="RTM">
    <REFERENCES DATA="{current-date()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </REFERENCES>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PGBLK">
    <REF>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TASK"/>
    </REF>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TASK">
    <PGBLK>
        <xsl:value-of select="../((@CHAPNBR, @SECTNBR, @SUBJNBR, @PGBLKNBR)/string(), '0')" separator="-"/>
    </PGBLK>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="@CHAPNBR, @SECTNBR, @SUBJNBR, @FUNC, @SEQ" separator="-"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZP2

Comment: Holy Cow!!! Thank you! Thank You! Thank You! :) :) :)  I'm trying so hard to understand XSLT and obviously need to work on understanding the <xsl:template match> <xsl:apply-templates> more... thank you so much again!! This is awesome!!